# WXPython error handling and repeated uses

Tags: python, error-handling, wxpython, progress-bar

I have a wx python application that performs a series of steps for a particular input when you click on a button.  The application works the first time, but then it throws an error if I try to click on the button a second time with a different input value.

I have two questions:
1.) How do I fix my code below so that it stops throwing this error message?

2.) What specific code should I add so that any error message such as this one is shown to the end user in a dialog box?  I would like it to be able to gracefully kill the whole process that threw the error (starting with the button click) and replace the progress bar with a new dialog box that gives the error message and allows the user to click a button that will take them back to the application's main window so that they can try to click the button again to make it work with new input.  I am about to wrap this up in an exe file soon, but right now the only error handling I have is the error message in the python shell.  Since users will not have the python shell, I need the error messages to come up in the manner described in this paragraph.  Notice that my OnClick() function here instantiates a class.  I make use of a number of different classes in my actual code, each of which is very complex, and I need the functionality I am asking for here to be able to handle errors that happen deep in the bowels of the various classes that are being instantiated by the OnClick() function.

Here is a very simplified but working version of my code:

```
import wxversion
import wx
ID_EXIT = 130

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,wx.ID_ANY,title, size = (500,500), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)

        # A button
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Click Here", pos=(160, 120))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClick,self.button)

        # the combobox Control
        self.sampleList = ['first','second','third']
        self.lblhear = wx.StaticText(self, label="Choose TestID to filter:", pos=(20, 75))
        self.edithear = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(160, 75), size=(95, -1), choices=self.sampleList, style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        # the progress bar
        self.progressMax = 3
        self.count = 0
        self.newStep='step '+str(self.count)
        self.dialog = None

        #-------Setting up the menu.
        # create a new instance of the wx.Menu() object
        filemenu = wx.Menu()

        # enables user to exit the program gracefully
        filemenu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate the program")

        #------- Creating the menu.
        # create a new instance of the wx.MenuBar() object
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        # add our filemenu as the first thing on this menu bar
        menubar.Append(filemenu,"&File")
        # set the menubar we just created as the MenuBar for this frame
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        #----- Setting menu event handler
        wx.EVT_MENU(self,ID_EXIT,self.OnExit)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnExit(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnClick(self,event):
        #SECOND EDIT: added try: statement to the next line:
        try:
            if not self.dialog:
                self.dialog = wx.ProgressDialog("Progress in processing your data.", self.newStep,
                                            self.progressMax,
                                            style=wx.PD_CAN_ABORT
                                            | wx.PD_APP_MODAL
                                            | wx.PD_SMOOTH)
            self.count += 1
            self.newStep='Start'
            (keepGoing, skip) = self.dialog.Update(self.count,self.newStep)
            TestID = self.edithear.GetValue()

            self.count += 1
            self.newStep='Continue.'
            (keepGoing, skip) = self.dialog.Update(self.count,self.newStep)
            myObject=myClass(TestID)
            print myObject.description

            self.count += 1
            self.newStep='Finished.'
            (keepGoing, skip) = self.dialog.Update(self.count,self.newStep)

            **#FIRST EDIT: Added self.count = 0 on the following line**
            self.count = 0

            self.dialog.Destroy()

        #SECOND EDIT: Added the next seven lines to handle exceptions.
        except:
            self.dialog.Destroy()
            import sys, traceback
            xc = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
            d = wx.MessageDialog( self, ''.join(xc),"Error",wx.OK)
            d.ShowModal() # Show it
            d.Destroy() #finally destroy it when finished


    class myClass():
        def __init__(self,TestID):
            self.description = 'The variable name is:  '+str(TestID)+'. '

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MainWindow(None,-1,"My GUI")
app.MainLoop()
```

My actual code is A LOT more complex, but I created this dummy version of it to illustrate the problems with it.  This code above works when I run it in python the first time I click the button.  But if I try to click the button a second time, I get the following error message in the python shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath/GUIdiagnostics.py", line 55, in OnClick
    (keepGoing, skip) = self.dialog.Update(self.count,self.newStep)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_windows.py", line 2971, in Update
    return _windows_.ProgressDialog_Update(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "value <= m_maximum" failed at ..\..\src\generic\progdlgg.cpp(337) in wxProgressDialog::Update(): invalid progress value
```

---

**FIRST EDIT:** OK, I answered my first question above by adding

```
self.count = 0
```

above

```
self.dialog.Destroy()
```

in the code above.  But what about my second question regarding error handling in the code above?  Can anyone help me with that?  Surely, error handling in wxpython is a common issue for which there are known methods.  I am going to use py2exe to wrap this application up into an exe file.

---

**SECOND EDIT:** I answered my second question above with the try: , except: statement that I have added to my code above.  Funny, this is the first time that no one on stack overflow has been able to answer my question.  I am new to this type of programming, so a lot of things I am just picking up as they come.  This question is now answered.